# Как расширить TableView

Tags: javafx, fxml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу расширить по высоте `TableView`, все `layout'ы` перепробывал - ничего не помогает. Не понимаю в чем проблема.

Вставляю его в `center border pan`'а другого окна, кнопки регулируются, таблица - нет. По высоте все стоит на `MAX_VALUE`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Pagination?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <bottom>
      <HBox prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnAdd" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="ДОДАТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnEdit" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="ЗМІНИТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnDelete" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" text="ВИДАЛИТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <VBox>
         <children>
            <VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableView" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Pagination fx:id="pagination" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</fx:root>
```

Добавляю его сюда через
dictionaryBorderPane.setCenter((Node) mainListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

```html
<Tab fx:id="tabDictionary" onSelectionChanged="#handleDictionaryTab" text="Довідники">
                            <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                           <children>
                              <BorderPane fx:id="dictionaryBorderPane" prefHeight="975.0" prefWidth="1920.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                 <left>
                                    <JFXListView fx:id="mainListView" prefWidth="300.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                 </left>
                              </BorderPane>
                           </children></AnchorPane>
                            </content>
                        </Tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь **AnchorPane**

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: не помогает. 
я ставлю его в окно с помощью borderPane.setCenter((Node) таблица с 3 кнопками..)
если пихнуть только tableView тогда оно растягивает, но вместе с кнопками, которые внизу - не хочет. что можно сделать? кинул бы весь fxml файл, но только 1 строку вставляет

Comment: Покажите код. То место которое вы описали.

Comment: как я могу его сюда вставить? можете подсказать?

Comment: @ЛеонардоДикаприо добавьте его в вопрос. Фрагмент кода выделяется отступом в 4 пробела

Comment: добавил, в этой ситуации таблица по ширине раскрывается только по контенту столбцов, тоесть только на половину открыта.
она привязана к prefHeight не знаю почему

Comment: в добавленном фрагменте проблем не вижу. добавьте полный fxml файл в вопрос.

Comment: это и был полный fxml файл
обновил

Comment: тогда он не корректный. нет закрывающих тэгов.

Comment: добавил полный. есть тэги, без них он бы просто не запускался, если это те тэги о которых я думаю

Comment: закинул не тот файл, обновил снова

Comment: залил то на чем сейчас остановился, работа стоит, и в команде по fxml никто ничего подсказать не может. буду благодарен если пересмотрите код и дадите совет куда смотреть. Кнопка в углу растягивается, таблица ни в какую, ее регулировать можно только по prefHeight, prefWidth но это костыли( могу кинуть github

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Pagination?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <bottom>
      <HBox prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnAdd" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="ДОДАТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnEdit" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="ЗМІНИТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnDelete" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" text="ВИДАЛИТИ">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <VBox>
         <children>
            <StackPane alignment="TOP_RIGHT" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
               <children>
                  <JFXButton alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" ripplerFill="#ed6464" text="QWEQWE" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="#3b2d2d" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Pagination fx:id="pagination" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</fx:root>
```

Обратите внимание на `VBox.vgrow`

Comment: Обновил картинку с вашим кодом, когда добавил VBox.vgrow к pagination он растянулся, таблица все еще не хочет.
поставил MAX_VALUE по высоте и ширине, без него также
 спасибо за ответ